# sony xperia z1 whatsapp sound notification problem

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger, sony-xperia-z1

Hi I have the following problem.
I get whatsapp notification on the top of my screen when receiving new whatsapp message but I dont want any sound with it. 
I tried to look in whatsapp settings - notification tone - but it just lets me select different sounds for the pop up. No option to have no sound at all?

This is super frustrating as I get so many whatsapp messages and it keeps beeping every time unless I turn down the phone sound alltohether (which then also turns down the volume of incoming calls).
If anyone know how to solve this I would be greatful to hear...
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Update your Whatsapp Application from the Play Store.

I am using Version 2.11.277.

And in this version, I can turn off the notification sound by doing the following :

Whatsapp

1. Go to Settings
2. Select Notifications
3. Untick Conversation tones

Edit : In this version it is also possible to set the notification tone to None, this is also available under the Notifications Setting.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple
Under the phone settings you have different adjustable sound options.
You can reduce/mute the volume for notifications .Reducing/muting the notification sound will not have any effect on the Incoming calls.
To select the notification sound

1. From your Home screen, tap .
2. Find and tap Settings > Sound > Notification sound.
3. Select the sound to be played when notifications arrive.
4. Tap Done.